# How to get individual camera ID from the JSON using json path extractor

Tags: arrays, json, jsonpath

below is my JSON & I want to get individual camera `IDs` from that:

```
    {
  "requestId": "9016895864875078465",
  "payload": {
    "devices": [
      {
        "id": "8EQ45T14M2RJ9"
      },
      {
        "id": "78G6432OP1118"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I get the two `ids` by using

```
$.payload.devices[*].id

[
  "8EQ45T14M2RJ9",
  "78G6432OP1118"
]
```

**but how to get individual camera `ID`**

Comment: This is an `array` of `devices`. You can iterate `array` to get `id` of each `device`.

Comment: Don't we have direct JSON path extrator expression directly? reason is i want to use it in Jmeter

Comment: See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/6ukxfc9u/3/) fiddle.